# yarn doesn't upgrade package file

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

When I update my deps with `yarn upgrage-interactive`, it does update in yarn.lock file (and node_module ofc), but package.json still without updates.

How can I update my package.json deps accordingly to latest upgrade  packages, which in yarn.lock file?

And how is correct to make updates, so it will affect both yarn.lock n package.json files?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a good tool to do that.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade) Run it, then run `yarn` and all of your packages will be at their latest versions, updated in the package.json as well.

Be careful, though, as going through a process like this *might* break your app, especially if it's a major version update (or even a minor one), so the responsibility is still on you. If this concerns you, updating versions manually would be the best bet. If you're using VSCode, it gives intellisense for packages and package versions in package.json, which helps a lot.